# How to check if a specific thing exists in quick.db?

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

So i was making a discord game bot where you collect chracters by opening chests, but the problem is that the characters appear again when you already have them.

I used the method `db.push`

the code:

```js
if(has === true){
  console.log(has)
  let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Chest Opening | Clash Chest')
.setDescription("<@"+message.author+"> got:\n"+amount+" :coin:")
.setColor('RANDOM')
.setFooter('Created by Tahmid GS#1867')
 message.channel.send(embed)
  await db.fetch(`coin_${message.author.id}`)
  db.add(`coin_${message.author.id}`, amount)
}
else if(has === false){
  console.log(has)
await db.fetch(`troop_${message.author.id}`)
db.push(`troop_${message.author.id}`, nada)



let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Chest Opening | Clash Chest')
.setDescription("<@"+message.author+"> got:\n"+amount+" :coin:\n||Common: "+nada+"||")
.setColor('RANDOM')
.setFooter('Created by Tahmid GS#1867')
  
  message.channel.send(embed)

   await db.fetch(`coin_${message.author.id}`)
  db.add(`coin_${message.author.id}`, amount)
  await db.fetch(`card_${message.author.id}`)
  db.add(`card_${message.author.id}`, 1)
}
```

has is `let has = db.has(`troop_${message.author.id}`, nada)`
I used let has = db.has(`troop_${message.author.id}`.nada)
and let has = db.has(nada,`troop_${message.author.id}`)

But it doesn't seem to work, in the console is "false"

*nada is the random chracter*

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the database has a specific key. In the database under the key `troop_${message.author.id}` there is an array. You want to check if that array **includes** the character or not.

```js
let has = (db.get(`troop_${message.author.id}`) || []).includes(nada);
```

Also you might want to check for the possibility that `db.get()` returns `undefined` or something like that. In that case we call `.includes()` on an empty array. Instead of getting an error *TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined*.